# Testing/Demoing UIMotionEffects in the simulator or on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios-simulator

I'm trying to build some educational content for iOS and would like to show how the new UIMotionEffect stuff works in practice.  Currently there does not seem to be a way to do any UIMotionEffect stuff in the simulator, which makes sense. But even when trying to do Airplay or HDMI out means that UIMotionEffect's get turned off.  As a last resort I can of course just capture the live screen of a device with another camera, but I'd still prefer to do something like the demo from WWDC, although I'm sure they were using some special setting or something.  If anyone has any ideas and/or suggestions, that'd be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to figure out how to do this is through the use of a capture card. The Blackmagic Thunderbolt Shuttle is finicky but when it works it works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never...but I found this clever solution on GitHub by toco.

https://gist.github.com/toco/6727120

Just add the h. and m. files to your project. I've tested on AirServer on my Mac and it works great.